# Как из массива строк сделать массив чисел

Tags: php

Есть вложенный массив строк нужно с него сделать массив цифр. Как это возможно реализовать?

```
$mass2 = array (
Array (
  "9.40",
  "9.55"
),
Array (
  "10.37",
  "10.46"
),

Array (
  "13.45",
  "13.58"
),

Array (
  "14.10",
  "14.30"
)
)
```

Comment: https://php.ru/manual/function.floatval.html

Comment: а как вы пробовали?

Comment: откуда приходит массив?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mass3 = array();
foreach($mass2 as $arr) {$mass3[] = array_map('floatval',$arr);}
var_dump($mass3);
```

Comment: в php динамическая типизация, так что там еще непонятно числа или еще что то. И `foreach` в скобки надо обромлять `{}`

Comment: @Naumov если явно указано, что некая последовательность символов имеет тип – строка (а если эта последовательность заключена в кавычки – то это явное указание на то, что это – строка, и var_dump ясно показывает, что это – строки), то динамическая типизация не сработает. А касательно foreach – где вы увидели отсутствие фигурных скобок? И да, открою страшную тайну: фигурные скобки не обязательны. Разница лишь в том, что без них выполнится только первая команда, идущая за условием цикла.

Comment: Я знаю что необязательно, но это нечитабельно как и запись в одну строку что касается приведения типов то foatval, (float) и приведение типов в php ничем не отличаются как пример http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c00c7b3bc910687daa57caf670f56a50b1b5e930 приведения типов.

Comment: Все это описано в документации к php https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php